# Javascript browser effects initializing correctly but disappearing afterwards

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, ajax

This script will add x of x records, search box, next/previous, etc... 
This works fine upon initial browsing.  It is supposed to show up if the call is Ajax.  The call is fine.  If the user adds data which will then appear on this page, once you navigate back to the page, the javascript effects will disappear.  I don't mean clicking the back button on the browser, but using the appropriate website action links.

I am new to javascript...any ideas where I could start looking to see where the issue might lie?

```
@if (IsAjax)
{
  <script src="~/Scripts/app/datatable_bootstrap.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var dataTableSettings = {
                "bRetrieve": true, 
                "BDestroy": true, 
                "oLanguage": { "sEmptyTable": "No records found." },  
                "aoColumnDefs": [ 
                    { "bSearchable": false, "aTargets": [3] } 


                ]
            };

            // Initialize DataTable
            var dataTable = $('#datatableTransportation').dataTable(dataTableSettings);
            $('.dataTables_filter input').addClass('form-control');
            $('.dataTables_length select').addClass('form-control');
            dataTable.fnSort([[0, 'desc']]); // Sort by Column 1, descending
        });
    </script>

}
```